# Why it's not the same? (JS)

Tags: javascript

When I did this

```js
const newYears = new Date("1 January 2022")
const now = new Date()

function countdownTimer() {
  const distance = newYears - now
  console.log(distance)
}

countdownTimer()

setInterval(countdownTimer, 1000)
```

Got this

[image]

---

But when I did this

```js
function countdownTimer() {
  const newYears = new Date("1 January 2022")
  const now = new Date()
  const distance = newYears - now
  console.log(distance)
}

countdownTimer()

setInterval(countdownTimer, 1000)
```

Got this

[image]

Why?

Thanks

Comment: `new Date()` is generating a different object every time when it's on the function.

Comment: Don't add images of text. Just add that text, and use code markup.

Comment: I guess closures and scopes in Javascript is what you need to read up on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet will parse the date once, storing the value `now` of whatever the time was when you began running. This will then produce the same output over and over (20 times). The 20 next to the log means "the same log repeated 20 times".

The second output will get the value of `now` (and hence `distance`) each time it runs through the loop, meaning the value will change each time. In that situation each `console.log` will output a different number, and they will not be stacked.